# Nested foreach loop to linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert the below nested foreach loops to a linq query

```
foreach (SAP.MOD mod in mods){
    foreach (SAP.RefMod r in refs){
        if (mod.RefModId == r.RefModId){
            modLookup.Add(mod.Modcode, r.ModItem);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is modLookup a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from m in mods
            join r in refs on m.RefModIf equals r.RefModId
            select new {
                mod.Modcode,
                r.ModItem,
            };

foreach (var i in query)
    modLookup.Add(i.Modcode, i.ModItem);
```

... if modLookup is a dictionary you could do this instead of the `foreach`...

```
modLookup = query.ToDictionary(i=>i.Modcode, i=>i.ModItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var matches = mods.Join(refs,
  m => wo.RefModId,
  r => p.RefModId,
  (mod,ref) => new {mod.RefModId, mod.Modcode, ref.ModItem}
);
matches.All(x => modLookup.Add(x.Modcode, x.ModItem));
```

Comment: Don't use `.All(...)` like this... (Ignoring the fact that it probably won't work anyway as I highly doubt `modLookup.Add` returns `bool`).

Comment: I would agree, but he's looking for an all Linq answer, not a `for` loop.